# How to hack a device if I have their MAC address?

Tags: attacks

My wifi is used by many people so I have no proper solution against them. I can see their mac address. I want them to stop using my wifi.

Comment: See [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/56181/9312).

Comment: password-protect your wi-fi? =)

Comment: Use a proper WiFi protection protocol (WPA2), change your passphrase and use a non-guessable one, and maybe change the SSID of the network to something like "HONEYPOT" :-). Additionally, you can turn on MAC filtering if available. Not great protection, but it's on top of the rest, and it's free.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to stop them using your wifi you should increase your security, not *hack* them. In your router's wifi section there is a built-in mac filtering system that you can enable. You need to add your devices' mac address to the list and pick a mode. There are two main filtering modes there:

- Allow (whitelist): Allow mac addresses in the list, deny everyone
- Deny (blacklist): Deny mac addresses in the list, allow everyone

Comment: Note that MAC filtering is useless against most attackers: it's trivial to figure out what addresses are valid and set a wireless card to use one of the valid ones.